# World vectorial map including states and cities map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a project (commercial) where i need a map with an overlay that i can click and have an action.

The main issue is that this map should be only the borders and the name of the locality, which from what i discovered neither google maps or other maps service offer.

Other sources of data like http://www.naturalearthdata.com/ are not very reliable because they miss a lot of information and usually they provide information only about a few countries.

Example: http://mtbo16.fpo.pt/mtbo/files/loc/loc_en.html

I need exactly the example from the url, except that i need to show only borders and names.

Comment: Maybe you can make use of Google GeoCharts? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Comment: Thanks, this should do the trick. Do you have any ideas what i can do if i want to go a bit deeper to a lower level? GeoCharts provides only info to the provinces level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Google Maps API you have an option to style the maps:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

So you can hide everything except locality names and borders on your map. Please have a look at this example: http://jsbin.com/nepode/edit?html,output

You can create your custom style using this wizard:

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this: http://vectormap.info/category/free_vector_maps_downloads/free_vector_world_maps/ what I did is the opposite, hide the map layers but you can have the option to show & you can change the background style, etc. I don't know, up to you just take a look, might be useful